# slack bot sending direct message to user using aws lambda function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, aws-lambda, async-await, slack-api

I'm trying to send a direct message using [slack web api](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) to a user but I think my getSlackUser method which [gets all the available users](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list) does not complete in time for when I call slackId;

the console.log(slackId) gives undefined meaning it doesn't complete my api call with [bolt](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage/code)

how do I ensure getSlackUser method finishes (make it blocking) before it moves on to the rest?

```
const { WebClient } = require('@slack/web-api');
const { App } = require('@slack/bolt')

const rtm = new RTMClient(process.env.SLACK_OAUTH_TOKEN);
const web = new WebClient(process.env.SLACK_OAUTH_TOKEN);
const app = new App({
  token: process.env.SLACK_OAUTH_TOKEN,
  signingSecret: process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET
});


exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const slackId = await getSlackUser('example_real_name').id;
  console.log(slackId);
  await sendSlackMessage(slackId, 'Bot message');
}


sendSlackMessage = async (channel, message) => {
  await web.chat.postMessage({
    channel: channel,
    text: message,
    as_user: true
  });
}

getSlackUser = async(real_name) => {
  const result = await app.client.users.list({
    token: process.env.SLACK_OAUTH_TOKEN
  });
  console.log(result);
  return result.members.find((user) => user.real_name == real_name);
}
```

Comment: Is the console.log(result) displaying the list of users give something ? and if yes is there is this members array a real name mathing the input real_name ?

Comment: yes, it produces a response like shown here: https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is precedence on this line:

```
const slackId = await getSlackUser('example_real_name').id;
```

Since member access has a higher precedence (evaluated before) than await, it is effectively the same as:

```
const slackId = await (getSlackUser('example_real_name').id);
```

`getSlackUser` returns a Promise object, then its `id` member is undefined. Await waits for the undefined, which is `undefined`.

To fix this, make sure that the await is evaluated before the `.id`:

```
const slackId = (await getSlackUser('example_real_name')).id;
```